# yum update presents hponcfg-4.2.0-0.x86_64 conflict

Tags: linux, centos, yum, cacti

I am in the process of trying to get Cacti installed onto an HP DL360 running Centos 6.3.
Running `yum update` presents me with a few updates but when entering <kbd>y</kbd> it returns an error.

How can I solve this?

```
    [root@Server hponcfg]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Repository rpmforge is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: **.***.**.**
 * contrib: **.***.**.**
 * dell-omsa-indep: **.***.**.**
 * epel: **.***.**.**
 * extras: **.***.**.**
 * hp-sdr: **.***.**.**
 * updates: **.***.**.**
87 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package centos-release.x86_64 0:6-3.el6.centos.9 will be updated
---> Package centos-release.x86_64 0:6-5.el6.centos.11.2 will be an update
---> Package cpqacuxe.x86_64 0:9.10-22.0 will be updated
---> Package cpqacuxe.x86_64 0:9.40-12.0 will be an update
---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-284.el6_3.1 will be updated
---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-336.el6_5.2 will be an update
---> Package dracut-kernel.noarch 0:004-284.el6_3.1 will be updated
---> Package dracut-kernel.noarch 0:004-336.el6_5.2 will be an update
---> Package hp-health.x86_64 0:9.1.0.42-54.rhel6 will be updated
---> Package hp-health.x86_64 0:9.40-1602.44.rhel6 will be an update
---> Package hp-smh-templates.noarch 0:9.1.0.33-32.all will be updated
---> Package hp-smh-templates.noarch 0:9.4.0-1327.37 will be an update
---> Package hp-snmp-agents.x86_64 0:9.1.0.57-51.rhel6 will be updated
---> Package hp-snmp-agents.x86_64 0:9.40-2506.37.rhel6 will be an update
---> Package hpacucli.x86_64 0:9.10-22.0 will be updated
---> Package hpacucli.x86_64 0:9.40-12.0 will be an update
---> Package hpdiags.x86_64 0:9.1.0-301 will be updated
---> Package hpdiags.x86_64 0:9.5.0-938 will be an update
---> Package hponcfg.noarch 0:4.0.0-0 will be updated
---> Package hponcfg.x86_64 0:4.2.0-0 will be an update
---> Package hpsmh.x86_64 0:7.1.0-16 will be updated
---> Package hpsmh.x86_64 0:7.2.2-8 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch                          Version                                    Repository                      Size
=======================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 centos-release                          x86_64                        6-5.el6.centos.11.2                        updates                         20 k
 cpqacuxe                                x86_64                        9.40-12.0                                  hp-sdr                         5.6 M
 dracut                                  noarch                        004-336.el6_5.2                            updates                        122 k
 dracut-kernel                           noarch                        004-336.el6_5.2                            updates                         24 k
 hp-health                               x86_64                        9.40-1602.44.rhel6                         hp-sdr                         316 k
 hp-smh-templates                        noarch                        9.4.0-1327.37                              hp-sdr                         3.5 M
 hp-snmp-agents                          x86_64                        9.40-2506.37.rhel6                         hp-sdr                         963 k
 hpacucli                                x86_64                        9.40-12.0                                  hp-sdr                         6.5 M
 hpdiags                                 x86_64                        9.5.0-938                                  hp-sdr                          15 M
 hponcfg                                 x86_64                        4.2.0-0                                    hp-sdr                          40 k
 hpsmh                                   x86_64                        7.2.2-8                                    hp-sdr                          13 M

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade      11 Package(s)

Total size: 45 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/doc/hponcfg/readme.txt from install of hponcfg-4.2.0-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package hponcfg-4.0.0-0.noarch

Error Summary
-------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Often the way around such problems is to run:

```
yum update --skip-broken
```

Sometimes a first round of updates cleans up the field, so later runs don't leave out anything. If it is *really* tangled up, you can try running the update command a few packages at a time, cutting back those that block the update.

See if the offending file is perhaps a hand-tweaked configuration file.

You could try to remove the package:

```
yum erase hponcfg
```

(Careful! This might end up trying to erase lots of stuff.) Then install it again (should get the latest version), and try the full upgade again.

Sometimes all that is happening is that there is some hickup with the remote repository, cured by:

```
yum clean metadata
```

and trying again.

Some local messups can be cured by `package-cleanup` (check its manpage, it has lots of options). The conflict might be due to a duplicate package.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the RPM DB entry to get around circular dependencies, however, this should be a last resort:

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps hponcfg
yum update
```

Comment: This will leave any cruft only found in the old package on the filesystem, as well as stomp on any config files that may have been changed by hand.